# how to clean rust on chain (motorbike)?

Tags: motorcycle, rust, chain

slight rust on the side of the links of my bike chain. I'm runing with dry lube which is teflon based I think. The rust isn't deep. Can I go at it with a brass bristle brush, or will that damage it and the orings?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like WD40, and a soft cloth to rub the rust away. Then apply the right amount of chain lubricant and you will be good to go. You can use a brass bristle brush, provided you do it gently like [this guy in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qff_9ie3pnE). A toothbrush will also work. This is light surface rust and IMHO nothing to worry about too much.

Answer (score 6):

You can buy a special tool to clean the chain, it is normally circular/spiral shaped and you twist the brush as it runs along the length of the chain.

[image]

http://www.jpcycles.com/product/ZZ36383

Also, you can purchase a special chain lube tool, that basically hugs the chain and has a hole to insert a straw.

Comment: That 3-sided "Grunge Brush" at the bottom of the page you linked to is also very good.  Nice thick bristles.  Same idea tho - brush all sides of the chain.

Comment: Wow Mitchell. I've never seen that tool you mentioned.  Nice.  Thanks.

Comment: got one of those, but doubt it will remove rust? probably just good for removing grunge

Answer (score 0):

I use a brass brush and kerosene on my chains (both bicycle and motorcycle). it works great and i have never had a problem. i have read that WD40 is inadvisable on o-ring chains, as it can displace the lubrication behind the o-rings. not sure how accurate that is. My neighbor cleans his chain with WD40, and it hasn't flown off the bike while running yet...

Comment: Modern orings are made of neoprene and are resistant to the solvents in wd40. Older ones were made of silicone and would indeed dissolve.

Comment: interesting. I would have thought that kerosene would be more aggresive to the orings than wd40. I think brass brush and wd40 will do it for me